# pip cant install python-ldap into virtualenv

Tags: flask, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, python-ldap

I just wanted to rename my virtualenv so i did pip 
       `freeze > requirements.txt`
in old one and then `pip install -r req.txt` and all went well exept for python-ldap.
 Here is error given by pip:
(Btw I created virtual environment using virtualenvwrapper.)

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.19 -IModules -I/opt/openldap-RE24/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/LDAPObject.o

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fstack-protector-strong'

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzdelavanie/bin/python2 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-7Dvhke/python-ldap/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-PkGQ57-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzdelavanie/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7Dvhke/python-ldap
Storing debug log for failure in /home-fri/hojny/.pip/pip.log
```

`gcc -v` returns this:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.8.2-10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i586 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Debian 4.8.2-10)
```

Comment: This is a GCC error.  What version is it?  (use `gcc -v`)

Comment: gcc version 4.8.2 (Debian 4.8.2-10)

Comment: It *is* a GCC error; you simply want to update to 4.9.

Comment: @Makoto i m not admin, so i guess i cant, its school server

Comment: Go talk to the admin.  If it's for something related to a project, they *should* be willing to update it.

Comment: anyway, thanks, btw are u Tachibana Makoto? :p from Free Eternal Summer :p

Comment: Not that this is germane to anything, but I've had this moniker long before that came out.